# Установка cookie через wp_ajax_nopriv (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ajax

Данный хук позволяет ставить куки после отправки формы через `admin-ajax` (WordPress). Т.е. сначала отправляется форма, а уже затем отправляются куки. А как сделать наоборот: сначала отправляются куки, а уже затем (следующим запросом) отправляется форма?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_elementor_pro_forms_send_form', 'action_function_name_123' );
function action_function_name_123(){

    // Set-Cookie...

}
```

Comment: Очевидно устанавливать куку со страницы загружающей форму. Ваш КЭП.

Comment: @SeVlad да, но тогда она будет установлена даже у тех, кто не отправил форму.

Comment: Ну так ты определись что тебе надо - поставить куку ДО события (которое не факт что произойдёт) или уже зафиксировать факт свершения события. А может тебе и не кука надо и ты решаешь [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710)

Comment: @SeVlad действительно, может быть и XY. Просто ищу способ конкретно этот ajax-запрос как-то отметить, чтобы его можно было затем при помощи RewriteCond поймать.

Comment: Зачем? Какую задачу ты хочешь решить?

Comment: @SeVlad хочу заблокировать все внешние запросы к admin-ajax.php на уровне сервера, кроме формы обратной связи, а для этого нужно этот запрос как-то выделить на фоне других, т.к. в журнале все эти запросы выглядят одинаково `POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2`

Comment: Никак вы этого сделать не сможете. Поставите куку перед запросом, злоумышлиник тоже сможет поставить эту куку. Будете генерировать секретный токен, злоумышлник тоже сможет. Бросьте это занятие)

Comment: Ну как я и предполагал - проблема молотка.  Ида, даже сама идея ммм.. неправильная. [Вообще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455015) и [в частности](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html#zashhita-ispolzuem-nonce-i-proveryaem-prava)

Comment: Хотя.. теоретически решить можно через хтацесс (конкретика и возможности зависят от некоторых факторов). Но повторю:  блокировать этот файл - плохая идея.